# cmd refuses all commands

Tags: windows, command-line

With W7x64, all commands ("mkdir", "ping", "ipconfig", or the installed "composer") grant an "access refused" error.

I shut down firewall (Comodo), disabled UAC, launched cmd as administrator, created a brand new administrator session, checked and altered owning permissions (setting them to my account), and, of course, restarted the damn machine.

Last piece of information, but I don't think it has any relevance : system is on SSD.

Edit : Here is a screen shot:

[image: Edit : Here is a screen]

Comment: Have you checked the Security tab in C:/Windows/System32 Properties? Do you have Read/Execute permissions?

Comment: add screen shoot with the error will be helpful to help you

Comment: @Trae Abell : i guess so. But are rights needed for all listed users, or only those with my name ?

Comment: Just your name, check the security tab properties for ipconfig, etc see if they are different

Comment: Tried for ipconfig : i took ownership, then add "full control" privileges on the app. cmd > ipconfig : same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure what happened to my command line, but installing an alternative (I choose [conemu](https://conemu.github.io/)) makes things returning to their old self again.